# Android custom spreadsheet design

Tags: java, android, kotlin, xml-layout

I want to create a spreadsheet, use RecyclerView and Gridlayout with 100 rows and 100 columns, but when scrolling vertically it becomes very slow and sometimes stops, the xml of the item is a simple textview. I tried to use third-party libraries but it also has the same problem when I put 100 rows and 100 columns, but I saw in the play store that there are many applications that use a design similar to Google Sheet or Excel that the scrolling is very fluid, and I want to do something similar to that.

`<HorizontalScrollView><androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/tableRecyclerView" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager" app:spanCount="100" android:layout_margin="16dp" /> </HorizontalScrollView`

Comment: Do you want a solution in Java or in Kotlin? Please remove the other tag from the question.

Comment: in either of the two, thanks